# Derivative with regard to time wedge product

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-forms

Could anyone help me understand the second equality of the expression below? I have already tried to interpret as the derivative in relation to the time of the composition of two functions, ie the wedge product composed with the application that takes functional into functional, but could not.

This is found in Jesen's book, "Surfaces in Classical Geometries," page 227. Link http://library1.ga/_ads/802B98464DDA8737736FDF48F69E3F49
[image]

Comment: There's no way to begin to understand the notation unless one has a copy of the book. You should make your question self-contained if you want help.

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry, just because I do not know what the author is using that I can not solve the problem. I've searched the whole book, but I do not think how he made that passage.

Comment: I suspect I use the equations of structures, but I can not ...

Comment: @TedShifrin I have the same problem in the book as the Mancala. 
I put the book link in the post.

Comment: For future reference, StackExchange frowns upon relying upon links to pose your questions. If you want responses, you should make the questions self-contained. In part, this will force you to make sure you understand all the notation that you need to work with the question. In this case, you clearly did not do that. "I've searched the whole book" shows you really don't understand what you're doing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You obviously didn't search the whole book. The relevant equations are at the bottom of p. 225. When you use the product rule, you'll have
$$\frac d{dt}\Big|_{t=0}\omega^1_t\wedge\omega^2_t = \left(dg^1+\sum g^j\omega_j^1\right)\wedge\omega^2 + \omega^1\wedge\left(dg^2+\sum g^j\omega_j^2\right).\tag{$\star$}$$
Now when we proceed, we seem to discover that they have a sign wrong.
\begin{align*}
d(g^1\omega^2-g^2\omega^1) &= dg^1\wedge\omega^2 + g^1d\omega^2 -dg^2\wedge\omega^1-g^2d\omega^1 \\
&=dg^1\wedge\omega^2 + g^1\sum\omega^j\wedge\omega_j^2 - dg^2\wedge\omega^1 - g^2\sum\omega^j\wedge\omega_j^1 \\
&=dg^1\wedge\omega^2+\omega^1\wedge dg^2 + g^1\omega^1\wedge\omega_1^2-g^2\omega^2\wedge\omega_2^1.
\end{align*}

Expand the right-hand side of ($\star$) and you'll get exactly this *plus* the $g^3$ terms in their equation (taking into account their comments).

Comment: Sorry Ted, it's because I'm new to the area, so the doubts are pretty basic. I have little familiarity with the properties of the wedge product and the $d$ operator.  I used the equations on page 225, but I think my problem was to understand why that equality is worth it? If you can answer me, I thank you! $d(g^1\omega^2-g^2\omega^1) = dg^1\wedge\omega^2 + g^1d\omega^2 -dg^2\wedge\omega^1-g^2d\omega^1$

Comment: You need to go back and learn the basics of differential forms. This book is quite sophisticated. Look up the product rule!